# I need some help to recover lost ether on myetherwallet

Tags: ether, myetherwallet, recovery

a couple of years ago I transfered some eth from Binance to myetherwallet to benefit from EoS and KeOs ( with hindsight I shouldn't have done as binance covered them) - notwithstanding I am not a technical person and inbetween that and time elapsing and metamask/my ether wallet upgrading I have lost the private keys to this wallet and therefore transaction. I believe I may have the Jason manifest file and I have the advanced KYC at binance for proof of providence - I think I would like to be able to reverse the transaction back onto binance ( have full KYC there) - or recover the ether if there is another route - can anyone help in any way?

Comment: In order to recover the private key, you'll need the UTC file (what you've referred to as "the Jason manifest file" in your question), and the password.

Comment: thank you - I have several pwds for etherwallet/metamask obviously not sure which one is for the ether wallet - I have UTC's I can't confirm they are for the right wallet - what do you think is the next step? thanks in advance

Comment: kind of but it probably wont work for mer - I don't have the programming knowledge to follow those instructions - I don't even know how to set up a new folder after downloading it - I need a service I can pay for I believe...thanks once again

Comment: You don't know how to create a new folder on your pc or mac?????